# Best classes to take

Tags: soft-question

I want a class that will help me improve my intuition on geometric spaces. All the math classes I have taken this far has been computational heavy and didn't help me understand the concepts other than knowing how to compute. I took linear algebra this semester, which I enjoyed -- it was the first math class that I actually had a small, intuition understanding of the concepts. It was heavy on proofs, even though I never did proofs before, I struggled at it, but it did help me understand the topics a lot better.

Which classes will help me further understand all the concepts discussed in linear algebra like Euclidean space and so on. Which class are best for me: Algebraic Topology, Complex Analysis, Analysis $I$, Abstract Algebra?

Comment: I like to recommend people take abstract algebra early since it gets you familiar with the language of higher math, in addition to its own content.  Then again, I am an algebraist.

Comment: What do you mean by "further understand all the concepts discussed in linear algebra"?  Unless you're asking about seeing linear algebra over other fields (or rings), or in infinite dimensions, I'd say the best course to learn about linear algebra is linear algebra, preferably an "honors" course with lots of proofs.

Comment: @JasperLoy I will edit my question to minimize the vagueness but it is closed. Why is it closed for?

Comment: @JasperLoy Did not know that. Sry for that then.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thank you very much for informing me on that because after taking a year and half of computational heavy math courses, I jumped right into a proof related class, in linear algebra, that I struggled in because I have never seen that type of math before. I hope that abstract algebra will help clarify all the issues I had in linear algebra.

Comment: @JesseMadnick What I meant by that was that all my math courses prior to linear algebra was strictly computational heavy, I have never seen proofs before and then boom linear algebra comes and its all proofs, which I struggled in because I have never seen that type of math before. Which got me thinking what class should I have taken prior to help me understand the concepts of proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jasper says in the comments, it really does depend on what the exact content of the courses are.  It would help if you could edit your question to include a rough syllabus for each course.  But here's my two cents:

Of the four courses you listed, I'd say that **algebraic topology** will be the best at developing geometric intuition.  Depending on how it's taught, there may be lots of proofs, or there may be very few.  However, I think that **the other three courses** you listed are generally considered somewhat more fundamental to an undergraduate math education.

Your **complex analysis** class will probably involve lots of computation, but hopefully there will be quite a few proofs as well.  In the sense that calculus can be considered geometric, I would say that complex analysis also contains many beautiful geometric ideas.

Both **Analysis I** and **Abstract Algebra** should involve lots of proofs, and not much rote calculation.  Analysis I will help you understand the functions on euclidean space, and abstract algebra will study groups (which could be regarded as generalizations of vector spaces).  Both of these courses are *really important* for any math major.

However, all of this is just my opinion.  Perhaps other people will think differently.  Before accepting any answers, I would suggest waiting at least a day or two so that others will be encouraged to provide alternative viewpoints.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take your advice and take Analysis and Abstract Algebra. Should I take these classes before signing up for Algebraic Topology?

Comment: That's usually how it's done, but you should ask the professors (and other students) at your university.  Again, it really depends on how the algebraic topology course is taught.